# SQL query - get ids - Advanced Custom Fields / WPeC

Tags: custom-post-types, mysql, plugin-wp-e-commerce, advanced-custom-fields

I need to query the database on add_action( 'init', '...') to find post ids with the field 'product_discount_option' set to true.

I know at least one of my product posts have the field 'product_discount_option' set to true. However when i run the SQL query below and var_dump it outputs an empty array ,  array(0) { } ..

```
add_action( 'init', 'retrieve_product_ids');

function retrieve_product_ids(){
global $wpsc_cart, $wpdb;

    $product_ids = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT object_id FROM `".WPSC_TABLE_META."` WHERE `meta_key` = 'product_discount_option' AND meta_value = true" ) );

    var_dump($product_ids);
}
```

The field 'product_discount_option' has been setup using the Advanced Custom Fields Plugin. The posts are WPeC custom post types, post_type = 'wpsc-product'.

I'm new to SQL queries, sorry if i've missed anything in the question.

thanks Cam

Comment: Is your constant set? Try `var_dump` with your query string alone-- none of the `$wpdb` stuff. Something like `var_dump("SELECT object_id FROM....")` Does the query look sane?

Comment: hey s_ha_dum, the constant WPSC_TABLE_META returns sb_wpsc_meta. will try var_dump'ing the sql query now. one moment..

Comment: string(103) "SELECT object_id FROM `sb_wpsc_meta` WHERE `meta_key` = 'product_discount_option' AND meta_value = true"

Comment: That looks OK if it matches your table structure. I am betting that the type for your meta_value column is  some kind of string (varchar, longtext, something) so I'd stick quotes around 'true' just to be safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your help s_ha_dum,

I had a look at the table structure using phpMyAdmin,
ACF Plugin saves fields to the postmeta table, so sb_wpsc_meta needed to be changed to sb_postmeta. also needed to change what was being SELECT to post_id aswell as the meta_value to 1.

final query;

```
"SELECT post_id FROM sb_postmeta WHERE `meta_key` = 'product_discount_option' AND meta_value = 1"
```